# Every finite subgroup of $G$ is contained in a unique maximal finite subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm asked to prove the following statement:

> given the s.e.s $$ 1 \to \mathbb{Z}^n\xrightarrow{i} G \xrightarrow{\rho} \mathbb{Z}/(p) \to 1$$
>   ($G$ is discrete and $p$ is prime) prove that for any finite subgroup $H$ of $G$, $H$ is contained in a unique maximal finite subgroup $M$.

**What I did so far** I've proved that every such $H$ can't be properly contained in another finite subgroup. But I don't know how to show that there is only one of such $H$ (i.e. uniqueness of finite maximal subgroup).

Any hints?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, or some information is missing: so $\;G\;$ is an abelian group containing (an isomorphic image of) the free abelian group of rank $\;n\;$ , and there exists a surjection from $\;G\;$ to the cyclic finite group of order $\;p\;$ (a prime, I guess), and also $\;\phi\circ i=0\;$ , which means the whole $\;\Bbb Z^n\;$ inside $\;G\;$ is mapped to zero in $\;\Bbb Z_p\;$ ...? And then you say that "any such $\;H\;$ (what, any finite subgroup of $\;G\;$?) is maximal"? I'm already pretty confused.

Comment: I don't know if it has to be abelian, I'm thinking about some semidrect product which can happen to be non-abelian. Yes $p$ is prime, didn't mentioned that, my bad.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: $H$ is a finite subgroup (non trivial course), as I said above. It has to be maximal since if we take $H_1\subset H$ a non trivial finite subgroup contained in $H$, then the restriction of $\rho$ to $H$ is injective buy the only possibility is that $H_1=H$, since $p$ is prime

Comment: But don't you have to prove, for $\;H\;$ a finite subgroup to be maximal, that there is no non-trivial $\;H_1\;$ containing it and not the other way around as you did?

Comment: If $G$ is abelian and you prove existence, then uniqueness is trivial (necessarily there is a unique maximal finite subgroup).

Comment: @Joanpemo maybe I messed up something, I proved (I think I have at least) that any finite subgroup (non trivial), can't be properly contained in another finite subgroup.

Comment: @Crostul would you mind elaborate it a little bit? I'm not sure I'm following your reasoning

Comment: @LuigiM Thank you, but you did prove that $\;H\le G\;$ finite and $\;H_1\le H\;$ then $\;H_1=H\;$ . This doesn't prove H is maximal . If at all, it'd prove it is minimal.

Comment: @Joanpemo I'm confused now. I proved that chosen an $H$ finite non trivial subgroup, then it can't be properly contained in another finite subgroup. I'd call it a kind of *maximality*. Maybe it's not standard notation though

Comment: @LuigiM Please read your comment above (second one), where you explain me what you did: you did NOT prove $\;H\;$ cannot be contained in another finite subgroup. What you did prove (apparently) is that no other subgroup can be contained in it!

Comment: @Joanpemo isn't it the same? I mean, everything boils down to the fact that any finite non trivial subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$. So they donate have any non trivial subgroup. Which means that they can't be contained properly in another finite subgroup, since the latter would itself be cyclic of order $p$, and it can't have any proper subgroups in it.

Comment: @LuigiM Now your last explanation is understandable to me, yet I don't think it is the same. Yes, I agree that any finite subgroup of $\;G\;$ would have to be isomorphic with $\;\Bbb Z/(p)\;$ and thus can't contain non-trivial subgroups. I guess it was also a matter of notation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer dealing the case when $G$ is abelian.

Fact 1: For every $F \le G$ nontrivial finite subgroup, $\rho|_F: F \to \Bbb{Z}/(p)$ is an isomorphism.

Proof of fact 1: Since $\ker \rho|_F$ is a torsion subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}^n$, it is $0$. This means that $\rho|_F$ is injective. Surjectivity follows from the fact that $\Bbb{Z}/(p)$ has no nontrivial subgroups.

In particular, every finite subgroup of $G$ has $p$ elements. This does not require that $G$ is abelian.

Fact 2: If $G$ is abelian, then $G$ has at most one nontrivial finite subgroup $F$.

Proof of fact 2: Suppose by contradiction that $G$ has at least two nontrivial finite subgroups $A,B$. By fact 1, they are isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/(p)$. By fact 1, we have also
$$A+B = \{ a+b: a \in A , b \in B\} \cong \Bbb{Z}/(p) \oplus \Bbb{Z}/(p)$$
is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/(p)$: this is a contradiction.

Comment: I see the point of fact $2$. I was trying to do that in the non-abelian case but 1) $AB$ is not necessarily a group, and 2) don't have an estimate for the size of $AB$. Thanks for this (partial) answer!

Comment: @Crostul Thank you. Isn't Fact 1 true no matter whether $\;G\;$ is abelian or not? And what do we need Fact 2 for?

Comment: @Joanpemo First question: yes. Second question: from fact 2 we have that all finite subgroups are exactly $0$ and $F$, and thay are contained in $F$ which is the unique maximal finite subgroup of $G$.